# The usage of "assign"

Tags: word-usage

Suppose the following assignment:

> X=20

I know that the common phrase is:

> 20 is assigned to X

How can I say the sentence in reverse order, to begin with X?

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary?

Comment: @user26 yes, but its example wasn't about a variable and a value. Also check my modification.

Comment: I would suggest that you try to understand the definition instead.

Comment: @user26 I read that and I guess the first one is correct but my question is different. Please read my question and don't repeat general advice.

Comment: @user26 but all are not agee that both are correct. Also I asked several related questions. Check them again.

Answer (score 2):

Given your two choices

> - Assigning a value to a variable
> - Assigning a variable to a value

I'd find the first one easier to understand.

Let's take computer programming as the example.
In some programming languages, "=" is the "assignment operator". 
`$a = 5;`
I can read this as "$a becomes equal to 5" or "let $a be(come) equal to 5" or "Assign the value 5 to the variable $a".

In this context, nothing can be "assigned to" a value. I could make a grammatical argument that second just means the same as the first, but it just strikes me as a common accidental reversal.

Edit after OP's Major edit:
Borrowing from  user2684291
You could say "Assigning X 20".

Or perhaps in a sentence fragment *By assigning X 20, we can calculate...*

Comment: I want to use the variable first, maybe "setting $a to 5" but I also thought "assigning $a **with** 5" works. does it work?

Comment: Check my own answer too.

Comment: Yes, _setting $a to 5_ is fine. "Here we set $pi to 3.14 so that we can..."

Comment: Here's another NGram to show the popularity of the two phrases: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=value+to+a+variable%2Cvariable+to+a+value&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvalue%20to%20a%20variable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvariable%20to%20a%20value%3B%2Cc0

Comment: A major edit to the OP question has left my answer seeming a little strange, but still relevant.

Comment: in your comments toward me you forgot @Ahmad. Otherwise, I won't be notified about your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose either is correct depending on context.

If you were defining a math problem for example, 
5 + 6 = 11 to make this equation a math problem I would assign one of the values a variable. 5 = x, therefore x + 6 = 11 making it a problem.

Vice versa..

In order to solve the equation I would assign the variable a value, x = 5 by progress of elimination to figure out the correct value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Imagine that a value is a number. And variable is the thing which declares the number.
Math example:

a=15;  a=variable. 15 is a value of "a" variable.

Comment: You didn't say how it depends.

Answer (score 0):

In the example:

> X = 20

20 **is assigned to** X.

If you want to change the order you can say:

X **is set to** 20

If you want to use the same **assign** verb, you can say:

X **is assigned the value** 20.

Comment: Google NGram does not support this https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assigned+with%2C+set+to&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cassigned%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cset%20to%3B%2Cc0 , (Greater than zero support, but not much greater than zero.)

Comment: This isn't the only interpretation, since the OP doesn't know what assignment means. Please provide more context.

Comment: @user2684291 The answerer is the OP.

Comment: @user2684291 Ooops! why no one care to the use of "with" in my question, I know what "assignment" means, but my purpose was how to reserve the order.

Comment: @TecBrat I was forced to narrow my question to my main concern.

Comment: You can say: "*the value* is assigned to *the variable*" or "*the variable* is assigned *the value*" with no difference in meaning (or the reversal of the assignment operator; assuming `variable = value` to mean `variable <- value`).

Comment: @user2684291 you probably meant "*the variable is assigned to the value*" in you comment, right?

Comment: I didn't. That would convey a slightly different (and the opposite) meaning.

Comment: @user2684291 Then what I was looking for is "the variable is assigned the value" without "with". right? thank you!

Comment: @user2684291 You should probably post "X **is assigned the value** 20"  as an answer so it can be accepted.